# mapbox layer minzoom/maxzoom doesn't works sometimes

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I've 3 layers
- one for clustered points (L1)
- one for unclustered points to appear as clustered (L3)
- one for unclustered points (L2)

I've setted the minzoom and maxzoom level of the layers in order to:
- when zoom > 9 (far), appears only L1 and L3
- when zoom < 9 (near), appears only L2

All works fine for L1 and L2, with the transition for zoom level.
Instead, the layer L3 appears always in map.

```
            GeoJsonSource source = new GeoJsonSource(
                    "sourcePoiItems",
                    featureCollection,
                    new GeoJsonOptions()
                            .withCluster(true)
                            .withClusterMaxZoom(8)
                            .withClusterRadius(15)
                            .withMinZoom(0)
                            .withMaxZoom(9)
                            .withTolerance(10));
            GeoJsonSource source2 = new GeoJsonSource(
                    "sourcePoiItems2",
                    featureCollection,
                    new GeoJsonOptions()
                            .withCluster(false)
                            .withMinZoom(9)
                            .withMaxZoom(16));
            GeoJsonSource source3 = new GeoJsonSource(
                    "sourcePoiItems3",
                    featureCollection,
                    new GeoJsonOptions()
                            .withCluster(true)
                            .withClusterMaxZoom(8)
                            .withClusterRadius(10)
                            .withMinZoom(0)
                            .withMaxZoom(9)
                            .withTolerance(10));
            mapboxMap.getStyle().addSource(source);
            mapboxMap.getStyle().addSource(source2);
            mapboxMap.getStyle().addSource(source3);
            SymbolLayer unclustered = new SymbolLayer("unclustered-points", "sourcePoiItems2");
            unclustered.setProperties(
                    PropertyFactory.iconImage(get("icon")));
            mapboxMap.getStyle().addLayer(unclustered);

            //relevant part

            CircleLayer circles = new CircleLayer("cluster-3", "sourcePoiItems3");
            circles.setProperties(
                    PropertyFactory.circleColor(layers[0][1]),
                    PropertyFactory.circleRadius(18f)
            );
            circles.setFilter(
                    not(has("point_count"))
            );
            mapboxMap.getStyle().addLayer(circles);

            SymbolLayer count1 = new SymbolLayer("count1", "sourcePoiItems3");
            count1.setProperties(
                    PropertyFactory.textField(Expression.literal("1")),
                    PropertyFactory.textSize(12f),
                    PropertyFactory.textColor(Color.WHITE),
                    PropertyFactory.textIgnorePlacement(true),
                    PropertyFactory.textAllowOverlap(true)
            );
            count1.setFilter(Expression.not(Expression.has("point_count")));
            mapboxMap.getStyle().addLayer(count1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a working test case for what you're seeing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. After tries I've seen that the minzoom and maxzoom for layer doesn't work perfectly, sometimes works other not. So I've implemented this behavior through Expression zoom.